# How to use locate function for string?

Tags: mysql

How to use locate function for string if string is present in database field?
I want to find location of "m/l" such string. below query return 0 to me however it is present in database table

```
SELECT locate('"m\/l":"',field) FROM table_name.
```

Comment: That is how [the documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/string-functions.html#function_locate) indicates it works. Do you have some sample data you can show here?

Comment: actually I have data in json format for field
{"xs":"","s":"","m":"","l":"","xl":"","xxl":"","xs\/s":"","m\/l":"2","xl\/xxl":"1"}

And trying to get value from json data..
SELECT 
substring_index(substr(size,locate('"s":"',size)+char_length('"s":"')),'"',1)
but it unable to locate such value as mentioned above

Comment: Why is the string `"m\/l"` and not `"m/l"`? That backslash shouldn't be there. I think it's causing your problems. You may need to double, triple, or quadruple it up in your SQL statement depending on where that's coming from and how many layers of string it's buried in. If it's in another language being passed in as a string, backslashes often get collapsed out.

Comment: Yes you are right but I am doing maintenance project and it is not possible to remove it as it is using in live server

Comment: I'd try using more backslashes. Every layer of string doubles it, so they can get *really* crazy in some cases. `\/` is *literal*-slash. `\\/` is *literal*-backslash slash, for example. On one occasion I had to use eight backslashes in a row to get it to encode as one at the end.

Comment: any alternative solution?

Comment: Did you try more backslashes in your `LOCATE` string?

Comment: Yes it works now..you great

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're dealing with escaped strings, you may need to crank up the escaping significantly to get it to work. Backslashes are special characters and will be collapsed down.

You may want to try:

```
LOCATE('"m\\/l":"',field)
LOCATE('"m\\\\/l":"',field)
```

If this is located inside another string, or two levels of string (e.g. inside JSON itself), you may need a *lot* of them.